# Generic interface in foundation, implementation in Feature - does this break Helix principles?

Tags: helix, solution-architecture

If I had a foundation project which needed to call multiple features and I achieved this by creating a generic interface that was implemented in those features would this break Helix principles? Only the foundation project itself would be calling the interface.

There would be no explicit dependency on the features (from the foundation project) only on the interface in foundation, however I can't help but visualise it as the foundation calling the feature even if it knows nothing of the implementation.